# Multi-window application crashing event loop in window 3 and 4 even though the same operation works in window 2

Tags: pysimplegui

I'm attempting to make a simple 4 window GUI. The first window a home window and the subsequent 3, seperate functions. I want to navigate to windows 2, 3 and 4 from the home window and be able to "do stuff" and return to home. Here's a minimum workable version of my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def make_function1_window():
    
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Calculate Function 1")],
        [sg.Text("0.0000", justification="right", background_color="#2a2a2a", text_color="white", relief="sunken", key="_DISPLAY_")],
        [sg.Input("Enter input...", justification="left", key="_F1_INPUT_")],
        [sg.Button("Calculate"), sg.Button("Home")]
    ]

    return sg.Window("Function1", layout)

def make_function2_window():
    
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Calculate Function 2")],
        [sg.Text("0.0000", justification="right", background_color="#2a2a2a", text_color="white", relief="sunken", key="_DISPLAY_")],
        [sg.Input("Enter input...", justification="left", key="_F1_INPUT_")],
        [sg.Button("Calculate"), sg.Button("Home")]
    ]

    return sg.Window("Function2", layout)

def make_function3_window():
    
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Calculate Function 2")],
        [sg.Text("0.0000", justification="right", background_color="#2a2a2a", text_color="white", relief="sunken", key="_DISPLAY_")],
        [sg.Input("Enter input...", justification="left", key="_F1_INPUT_")],
        [sg.Button("Calculate"), sg.Button("Home")]
    ]

    return sg.Window("Function3", layout)


layout_home = [
    [sg.Text("Welcome to the program", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))],
    [sg.Button("Function 1"), sg.Button("Function 2"), sg.Button("Function 3")],
    [sg.Button("Exit")]
]

home_window = sg.Window("Program Home", layout_home)
function1_active = function2_active = function3_active = False


while True:

    if not function1_active:
        event, values = home_window.read()
        if event is None or event == "Exit":
            break

    if not function1_active and event == "Function 1":
        function1_active = True
        home_window.hide()
        function1_window = make_function1_window()

    if not function1_active and event == "Function 2":
        function2_active = True
        home_window.hide()
        function2_window = make_function2_window()

    if not function1_active and event == "Function 3":
        function3_active = True
        home_window.hide()
        function3_window = make_function3_window()

    if function1_active:
        event, values = function1_window.read()
        if event == None:
            break
        elif event == "Home":
            function1_active = False
            function1_window.close()
            home_window.un_hide()
        elif event == "Calculate":
            function1_window["_DISPLAY_"].update(value="Doing stuff")
            function1_window.refresh()

    if function2_active:
        event, values = function2_window.read()
        if event == None:
            break
        elif event == "Home":
            function2_active = False
            function2_window.close()
            home_window.un_hide()
        elif event == "Calculate":
            function2_window["_DISPLAY_"].update(value="Doing stuff")
            function2_window.refresh()

    if function3_active:
        event, values = function3_window.read()
        if event == None:
            break
        elif event == "Home":
            function3_active = False
            function3_window.close()
            home_window.un_hide()
        elif event == "Calculate":         
            function3_window["_DISPLAY_"].update(value="Doing stuff")
            function3_window.refresh()
                  
     
home_window.close()
```

The GUI navigates correctly for the home window and window 2. However, if you click the "calculate" event on windows 3 and 4 the event loop seems to crash, even though the functionality of windows 3 and 4 is exactly the same as window 2.

I'd be grateful for any help on this issue.

Cheers,
Callum

I have tried adding the .refresh() command. I want to be able to use the "calculate" event on each window and then use another event.

Comment: What are the crash details or what does "seems to crash" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for win1 is different with the logic for win2 and win3, it will be back to main window read if you are in the win2 or win3 after `Calculate` button clicked, but the sub-window is shown and main window is hided.

IMO, you get the code complex and difficult to maintain.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def function_window(index):
    layout = [
        [sg.Text(f"Calculate Function {index}")],
        [sg.Text("0.0000", justification="right", background_color="#2a2a2a", text_color="white", relief="sunken", key="_DISPLAY_")],
        [sg.Input("Enter input...", justification="left", key="_INPUT_")],
        [sg.Button("Calculate"), sg.Button("Home")]
    ]
    window = sg.Window(f"Function{index}", layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Home"):
            break
        elif event == "Calculate":
            window["_DISPLAY_"].update(value="Doing stuff")
    window.close()

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Welcome to the program", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))],
    [sg.Button("Function 1"), sg.Button("Function 2"), sg.Button("Function 3")],
    [sg.Button("Exit")]
]
window = sg.Window("Program Home", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event.startswith("Function"):
        index = event.split(" ")[1]
        window.hide()
        function_window(index)
        window.un_hide()

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the logic must have been incorrect, though I'm not sure where. I solved the problem via:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

function1_active = function2_active = function3_active = False

def make_home_window():
    
    layout_home = [
        [sg.Text("Welcome to the program", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))],
        [sg.Button("Function 1"), sg.Button("Function 2"), sg.Button("Function 3")],
        [sg.Button("Exit")]
    ]
    
    home_window = sg.Window("Program Home", layout_home)
    
    return home_window


def run_function1_window():
    
    home_window.hide()

    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Calculate Function 1")],
        [sg.Text("0.0000", justification="right", background_color="#2a2a2a", text_color="white", relief="sunken", key="_DISPLAY_")],
        [sg.Input("Enter input...", justification="left", key="_F1_INPUT_")],
        [sg.Button("Calculate"), sg.Button("Home")]
    ]
    
    window = sg.Window("Function1", layout)  
    
    while True: 
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in [None, "Home", sg.WIN_CLOSED]:            
            break
        elif event == "Calculate":       
            window["_DISPLAY_"].update(value="Doing stuff")
    function1_active = False
    window.close()
    home_window.un_hide()
 
    return function1_active


def run_function2_window():
    
    home_window.hide()
       
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Calculate Function 2")],
        [sg.Text("0.0000", justification="right", background_color="#2a2a2a", text_color="white", relief="sunken", key="_DISPLAY_")],
        [sg.Input("Enter input...", justification="left", key="_F1_INPUT_")],
        [sg.Button("Calculate"), sg.Button("Home")]
    ]
    
    window = sg.Window("Function1", layout)  
    
    while True:  
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in [None, "Home", sg.WIN_CLOSED]:            
            break
        elif event == "Calculate":
            window["_DISPLAY_"].update(value="Doing stuff")
    function2_active = False
    window.close()
    home_window.un_hide()
 
    return function2_active


def run_function3_window():
    
    home_window.hide()
       
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Calculate Function 3")],
        [sg.Text("0.0000", justification="right", background_color="#2a2a2a", text_color="white", relief="sunken", key="_DISPLAY_")],
        [sg.Input("Enter input...", justification="left", key="_F1_INPUT_")],
        [sg.Button("Calculate"), sg.Button("Home")]
    ]
    
    window = sg.Window("Function3", layout)  
    
    while True:    
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in [None, "Home", sg.WIN_CLOSED]:            
            break
        elif event == "Calculate":
            window["_DISPLAY_"].update(value="Doing stuff")
    function3_active = False
    window.close()
    home_window.un_hide()
 
    return function3_active



home_window = make_home_window()

while True:
            
    if not function1_active:
        event, values = home_window.read()
        if event is None or event == "Exit":
            break

    if not function1_active and event == "Function 1":
        function1_active = True
        function1_active = run_function1_window()
        
    if not function2_active and event == "Function 2":
        function2_active = True
        function2_active = run_function2_window()
            
    if not function3_active and event == "Function 3":
        function3_active = True
        function3_active = run_function3_window()   
    
home_window.close()
```

The reason I create 3 separate functions for the windows is eventually they will be entirely different, it was just for the minimum working example I have them the same.

Thanks for your help!